# Trigger for automatic deletion from primary key contain table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to delete data from primary key Table if data not exists in Foreign key table. There are almost 25 child tables.

Comment: and what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . try to add the exact issue by posting image or the sample code .

Answer (score 0):

First, this should not be a trigger. Triggers are fired on specific actions, e.g. inserting a record. If you want to "cleanup" your table by deleting records not referenced by any child table, this is manual action executed on demand. So let's just generate a query, which will check all child tables.

We can find which are the child tables using [sys.foreign_keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-foreign-keys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) table. Then we will construct a query, and in the where clause we will put `and not exists` statement for each of the child tables referencing our main table. Because blindly deleting records is a bit dangerous, I will recommend you to generate a SELECT statement first and review the rows which are about to be deleted. If everything looks good, you can generate the actual DELETE statement and execute it.

The generated query will be printed in Messages tab of SSMS and you can copy/paste it in a query window to execute it. But if you want, you can simply execute it as dynamic SQL right after it is constructed.

The complete solution should look like this:

```
-- The name of the table, from which you want to delete rows
declare @TableName sysname = N'dbo.USERS'

declare @SqlStatement nvarchar(max)

-- Deleting is dangerous. First execute select statement and review the rows. Then uncomment the line bellow to generate delete statement
set @SqlStatement = N'select * from ' + @TableName + ' where 1=1'
--set @SqlStatement = N'delete from ' + @TableName + ' where 1=1'

-- Returns a list of foreign keys in your database
;with cteForeignKeys as (
select
    SCHEMA_NAME(po.schema_id) + '.' + po.name as ChildTableName
    , pc.name as ChildColumnName
    , SCHEMA_NAME(ro.schema_id) + '.' + ro.name as ReferencedTableName
    , rc.name as ReferencedColumnName
    , fk.referenced_object_id
from sys.foreign_keys fk
inner join sys.foreign_key_columns fkc on fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
inner join sys.objects po on po.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
inner join sys.columns pc on pc.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id and pc.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
inner join sys.objects ro on ro.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
inner join sys.columns rc on rc.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id and rc.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
)

-- Construct the where clauses for checking all child tables
select
    @SqlStatement += FORMATMESSAGE('
        and not exists(select * from %s where %s.%s = %s.%s)',
        ChildTableName, ChildTableName, ChildColumnName, 
        ReferencedTableName, ReferencedColumnName)
from cteForeignKeys
where referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)

-- This can print only first 4000 chars. With many child tables the query may exceed this limit
print @SqlStatement

-- Use multiple print statements to dump parts of the query to Messages window. Delete the line breaks between sections to be able to execute the query
print SUBSTRING(@SqlStatement,     1,  4000)
print SUBSTRING(@SqlStatement,  4001,  8000)
print SUBSTRING(@SqlStatement,  8001, 12000)
print SUBSTRING(@SqlStatement, 12001, 16000)

-- Or execute it directly as dynamic SQL
-- exec sp_executesql @SqlStatement
```